# Pytorch NLP Huggingface: model not loaded on GPU

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nlp, pytorch, torch, huggingface-transformers

I have this code that init a class with a model and a tokenizer from Huggingface.
On Google Colab this code works fine, it loads the model on the GPU memory without problems.
On Google Cloud Platform it does not work, it loads the model on gpu, whatever I try.

```html
class OPT:
    def __init__(self, model_name: str = "facebook/opt-2.7b", use_gpu: bool = False):
        self.model_name = model_name
        self.use_gpu = use_gpu and torch.cuda.is_available()
        print(f"Use gpu:: {self.use_gpu}")

        if self.use_gpu:
            print("Using gpu")
            self.model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
                self.model_name, torch_dtype=torch.float16
            ).cuda()
        else:
            print("Using cpu")
            self.model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
                self.model_name, torch_dtype=torch.float32, low_cpu_mem_usage=True
            )

        # the fast tokenizer currently does not work correctly
        self.tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name, use_fast=False)
```

The printed output is correct:

```html
Use gpu:: True
Using gpu
```

But the nvidia-smi says that there is no process running on the gpu:

```html
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 470.82.01    Driver Version: 470.82.01    CUDA Version: 11.4     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla T4            On   | 00000000:00:04.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   40C    P8     9W /  70W |      0MiB / 15109MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And with htop I can see that the process is using the cpu ram.

Comment: Can you also add the outputs of the following: torch.cuda.device_count() and torch.cuda.current_device()

Answer (score 5):

You should use the `.to(device)` method like this:

```
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
model = nameofyourmodel.to(device)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like with every PyTorch model, you need to put it on the GPU, as well as your batches of inputs using `.to(device)` method.

https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/is-transformers-using-gpu-by-default/8500
https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/2704